# How to convert an integer input(could be positive, negative or zero) of any size to its binary in VHDL?

Tags: binary, integer, type-conversion, vhdl

I don't want to use the numeric_std library as it is giving me some issues while using it with the system generator. The code by considering the numeric_std library is as:

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use ieee.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

    entity conversion is
         port(l: in integer; k: out std_logic_vector(127 downto 0));
    end conversion;

    architecture Behavioral of conversion is
    begin
         k <= conv_std_logic_vector(l,128);
    end Behavioral;
```

**What is an alternative to this method, keeping in mind that the input integer can have ANY value?**

Comment: I would suggest trying to solve the issue that is stopping you using `numeric_std`.

Comment: I require this code to be used as a black box in my system generator model. When I run it, the following error shows up.                            HDL simulation model compilation failed.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:104 - "xlisim_bit.vhd" Line 1904: Cannot find
<bit> in library <work>. Please ensure that the library was
compiled, and that a library and a use clause are present in the
VHDL file.

Comment: Never use `ieee.numeric_std` in conjunction with `ieee.STD_LOGIC` or `ieee.std_logic_arith`. They are incompatible. For new code, just use `ieee.numeric_std`; for existing code, you perhaps want to use whatever packages are already there.

Comment: I removed all package declarations except numeric_std and it showed syntax error of not being able to recognize std_logic_vector and the function conv_std_logic_vector

Comment: What is 'the system generator'?  And what issues are you having with it?

Comment: "System Generator" is a Xilinx tool that generates VHDL (I don't know of what quality) from some "high level" description. (and to @PriyankaGupta : there is no `conv_std_logic_vector` function in numeric_std : see Casper's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Numeric_std issues**

You may just need to get the following library inclusion. If you can't use numeric std due to some other code in your file, consider making your design a *component*, i.e. a separate entity. Entities are separate compile units, you so can just include the libraries like this:

```
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
```

**Conversion**

Then using numeric_std, you can convert an integer like this:

```
k <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(l, 127));
```

**32-bit limitation**

Beware that the integer type in VHDL is only a signed 32-bit integer, so you will never be able to cover the whole range of *k* this way.